# Using Friedman Test or Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test to compare two sets of Likert data

Tags: likert, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I distributed a questionnaire consisting two different sets of Likert statements. In the first section, I asked the respondents to rank some employee attributes (on 5–point Likert scale, 1 not important <> 5 very important) in order of importance for them; whereas in the second section, I asked the respondents to rank the same attributes in order of importance for their employer. The sample of my study consists of 93 respondents who were selected randomly.
I want to compare the responses of each attribute, which were placed on the two different sections of the questionnaire. Can I use Friedman Test or Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test to compare the data of two sets of Likert statements?

Comment: No doubt you *can* (who could stop you?); it's more a question of whether it makes sense and what the properties (actual significance level, power) of doing so would be ... and that depends partly on how you're finding p-values under ties.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thank you for your comment. My data is highly skewed, because most of the respondents ranked the attributes 4 or 5. I expected that (since the data are concentrated in such small range) there will be correlation between the responses of the same attribute within the two sections, which was proven by Spearman Rho test. However, Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test still suggesting that there is statistically significant difference between the responses of the same attribute within the two sections.

Comment: Do the results  of Spearman Rho test and Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test contradict each other, or it is fine to have correlated variables which their medians are significantly different?

Comment: Certainly the locations can differ when variables are correlated; those two things generally aren't related at all. Imagine if the first set were all 1 and 2 and the second set were all 4 and 5, and the 2's and 5's always came together in pairs (as did 1's and 4's). Then the correlation (by whatever common measure) would be 1, yet the locations (by any of the common measures of location) would differ by 3.